# Search CouchDB Using ElasticSearch River

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I've created a couchDB river (from this [elasticsearch example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/river/couchdb.html)) for elasticsearch with the following code:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/tasks/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "couchdb",
"couchdb" : {
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : 5984,
    "db" : "tasks",
    "filter" : null
},
"index" : {
    "index" : "tasks",
    "type" : "tasks",
    "bulk_size" : "100",
    "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
}
}'
```

When I try to search the the couchDB using elasticsearch with this command:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tasks/tasks -d query{"user":"jbattle"}
```

I get the response:
No handler found for uri [/tasks/tasks] and method [GET][]

I've been searching but have yet to discover a solution to/for this issue.

**UPDATE:**

I've discovered the proper query is:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_river/tasks/_search?q=user:jbattle&pretty=true'
```

Though, despite no longer receiving an error, I get 0 hits:

```
{
   "took" : 1,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
     "total" : 1,
     "successful" : 1,
     "failed" : 0
   },
   "hits" : {
   "total" : 0,
   "max_score" : null,
   "hits" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your queries are incorrect. The first one is missing the endpoint `/_search` and the second one is querying index `_river` instead of index `tasks`.

The `_river` index is where your river is stored not your data. When you configured your river, you specified index `tasks`.

So try this instead:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/tasks/tasks/_search?q=user:jbattle&pretty=true'
```

Or if that doesn't work, try searching for any docs in `tasks/tasks`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/tasks/tasks/_search?q=*&pretty=true'
```

clint

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was spot on. Now, I'll need to work on how I want the fields indexed.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[The example file](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb) you posted got moved to github.  These guys give [a decent walkthrough](http://www.ripariandata.com/blog/time-to-relax-installing-couchdb-and-elasticsearch) of getting couch and elasticsearch to work together.

Unfortunately, the currently accepted answer doesn't work for me.  But if I paste something like this in my browser's address bar it works.  Notice that there is only one reference to the "tasks" index in the url, not two.

```
http://localhost:9200/tasks/_search?pretty=true
```

To do a real search you could try something like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/tasks/_search?q="hello"&pretty=true
```